# Non-Static Variable Error

Tags: java

I am just beginning Java programming and I was following this example and I keep getting this "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static content" error. This code is supposed to print out the cadence, speed, and gear. I get the error at the `Bicycle bike1=new Bicycle();` and `Bicycle bike2=new Bicycle();`  Here is the code:

```
public class BicycleDemo 
{

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // TODO code application logic here
    Bicycle bike1= new Bicycle();
    Bicycle bike2= new Bicycle();

    bike1.changeCadence(50);
    bike1.speedUp(10);
    bike1.changeGear(2);
    bike1.printStatments();

    bike2.changeCadence(40);
    bike2.speedUp(12);
    bike2.applyBreaks(3);
    bike2.printStatments();
}

class Bicycle
{
   int cadence=0;
   int speed=0;
   int gear=1;

   void changeCadence(int value)
   {
       cadence=value;
   }
   void changeGear(int value)
   {
       gear=value;
   }
   void speedUp(int increment)
   {
       speed=speed+increment;
   }
   void applyBreaks(int decrement)
   {
       speed=speed-decrement;
   }
   void printStatments()
   {
       System.out.println("Cadence:"+cadence+"Speed:"+speed+"Gear:"+gear);
   }
}
```

Comment: Take your error message and search for it on Google or on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Paste full error message and stack trace...

Comment: change `class Bicycle` to `static class Bicycle` if you want to use it in the main method like that without putting it in a separate file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Bicycle` class is an inner class and cannot be directly instantiated in a `static` method. Just move it outside `BicycleDemo` class:

```
public class BicycleDemo {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Bicycle bike1= new Bicycle();
        Bicycle bike2= new Bicycle();

        bike1.changeCadence(50);
        bike1.speedUp(10);
        bike1.changeGear(2);
        bike1.printStatments();

        bike2.changeCadence(40);
        bike2.speedUp(12);
        bike2.applyBreaks(3);
        bike2.printStatments();
    }
}

//note the braces ( } ) up here

class Bicycle {
    //definition here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either change `class Bicycle` to `static class Bicycle` or, preferably, move it into a separate file (`Bicycle.java`).

Comment: Or make it a second class in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access non-static inner classes without having a referrence to the object of outer class.
In you case, you can't just instantiate `Bicycle bike1= new Bicycle();`

You work in static context (public static void main(String[] args)), so you have to create an instance of outer class (BicycleDemo) first, and then create instances of inner class.
In this case you need to write:

```
BicycleDemo demo = new BicycleDemo ();

Bicycle bike1= demo.new Bicycle();
Bicycle bike2= demo.new Bicycle();
```

...